# Port 8080 not listening when running Gunicorn HTTP server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python

I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/getting-started?authuser=1).
I installed my app dependencies using pip:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Then installed the Gunicorn HTTP server:

```
pip3 install gunicorn --user
```

but when I try to run the Gunicorn HTTP server on GCP :

```
~/.local/bin/gunicorn -b :8080 main:app
```

I get the following error :

[image]

When  I try to check the port 8080 with cmd:

```
 netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
```

nothing shows up.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Paste the text into your answer instead, so it's readable by screen readers and search engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running `netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"`. Are you running it with root permissions? If you run it just as your user, it won't be able to see everything.

Try running it again as the root user, or with sudo - also I would recommend using grep instead of find, like so: `netstat -a -n -o | grep 8080`.

Comment: I am running it as an admin and still no result

Comment: Be precise - what is the exact command you’re running? What is the output? It’s important to be exact on here as we cannot see your screen and have no knowledge of your setup.